悩みますと悩まされますの　違うのはなんですか
I don’t know how 悩みます　change from 悩まされます　through 形.

I provide morphological segmentation below for easier understanding:
悩{なや}む, nayam-u has polite form 悩{なや}みます, nayam-i-mas-u (here -i is suffix of Continuative (連用形{れんようけい}), -mas- is politeness suffix, and -u is suffix of Conclusive (終止形{しゅうしけい}) / Attributive (連体形{れんたいけい}) (they have merged in modern Japanese)).
(Politeness suffix is actually -mase, and -mase + -u → -masu. Compare its negative: -mase + -n → -masen, and older form -mase + -uru → -masuru; suffix -uru was never attached to consonant-stem verbs, which means that subsurface form of this suffix cannot be -mas and must be -mase. Past form -masita is irregular from etymological point of view, and expected form would -maseta.)
悩{なや}ます, nayam-as-u happens to have its own entry in dictionaries, but it can be also considered short causative form of 悩{なや}む mentioned above (long causative is 悩{なや}ませる, nayam-ase-ru). Causatives are created by suffixes -ase ~ -sase and -as ~ -sas (variants with initial s are attached to vowel-stem verbs; nayam- is consonant-stem verb).
悩{なや}ます, nayam-as-u has passive form 悩{なや}まされる, nayam-as-are-ru, which can be further conjugated to polite form 悩{なや}まされます, nayam-as-are-mas-u, which is seen in your example sentence. Passive form is created by suffix -are ~ -rare (variant with initial r is attached to vowel-stem verbs; nayam-as- is consonant-stem verb).
(Passive form for long causative 悩{なや}ませる, nayam-ase-ru, which is vowel-stem verb, would be 悩{なや}ませられる, nayam-ase-rare-ru, and its polite form would be 悩{なや}ませられます, nayam-ase-rare-mas-u.)
